# How style unordered list like a table?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

What is the best way to style unordered list for below HTML code:

```
<ul class="photo-grid">
    <li class="photo">
        <a href="#" class="photo-link">
            <img src="photo1_150x200.jpg" class="photo-img" />
            <span class="photo-title">this is my girl</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="photo">
        <a href="#" class="photo-link">
            <img src="photo2_150x200.png" class="photo-img" />
            <span class="photo-title">this_is_photo_for_anonymous_people</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to do this steps:

divide the page into 4 columns with an unknown number of rows

photo’s can be either portrait (150px X 200px) or landscape (200px X 150px), but I don’t know that upfront. A row can thus have only landscape, only portrait, or a mix of landscape and portrait photo’s

spacing between rows is always 10px

titles are vertically aligned to each other

Comment: you can just use a table :P

Comment: OK then , i will write an answer with some css , give me some time

Comment: @MohitBhasi Okay tyt

Comment: I'm not sure which is sadder: the fact that someone suggested using a table, or the fact that the OP thinks they're doing this just to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/oex9sd2o.

Also, vertically aligning texts in your variable heightened images situation is pretty difficult to achieve. It would extremely ease the process to go with regular table structure if you don't really need this `ul > li` structure.

Comment: Its work, but there is no rows! the columns overlap each other

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
First
</div>
<div id="two">
Two
</div>
<ul class="photo-grid">
    <li class="photo">
        <a href="#" class="photo-link">
            <img src="photo1_150x200.jpg" class="photo-img" />
            <span class="photo-title">this is my girl</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="photo">
        <a href="#" class="photo-link">
            <img src="photo2_150x200.png" class="photo-img" />
            <span class="photo-title">this_is_photo_for_anonymous_people</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#one {
    position: fixed;
    height: 23px;
    width: 35px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#two {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 27px;
    height: 23px;
    width: 35px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

***Do you want a table like this?***

If so, you could just manually css everything correctly into place yourself if you want!

Answer (score 0):

## Let's use the [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) and [`<figcaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) elements!

### Barebones example

This seems like a nice opportunity to pull out the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements:

```
<a href="#" class="photo-link">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150X200" />
      <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>        
    </figure>
</a>
```

- The `<figure>` elements are lined up with `display: inline-block`. `vertical-align: bottom` ensures the captions are lined up even with the varying image heights
- The 4 columns across are created with the `width: 850px` on the `.wrap`; just enough width to contain four 200 x 200px columns and their 50px of margins
- The `<figcaption>`'s are given a fixed height in this example, this ensures uniform height even with varying amounts of text.

#### Complete Example

- The background colours are just to show how the blocks are lined up.
- The closing and opening elements are hard up against each other — `<a><figure></figure></a><a><figure></figure></a>` — this [prevents an inline gap forming between them](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), which would throw out the alignment.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 850px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #999;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #F00;
}
.wrap a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none
}
/*Left margin only for first column of each row*/

.wrap a:first-child figure,
.wrap a:nth-child(4n+1) figure {
  background: #F80;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
/*Prevent baseline gap underneath image*/

figure img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
/*
Set height and padding for each caption.
*/

figcaption {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#" class="photo-link"><figure>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200X150" />
    <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
   </figure></a><a href="#" class="photo-link"><figure>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150X200" />
    <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure></a><a href="#" class="photo-link"><figure>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150X200" />
    <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
   </figure></a><a href="#" class="photo-link"><figure>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150X200" />
    <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure></a><a href="#" class="photo-link"><figure>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150X200" />
    <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
   </figure></a><a href="#" class="photo-link"><figure>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200X150" />
    <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure></a><a href="#" class="photo-link"><figure>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150X200" />
    <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
   </figure></a><a href="#" class="photo-link"><figure>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200X150" />
    <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure></a>
 </div>
```